# Is $\mathcal B(\mathbb R) \times \mathcal B(\mathbb R)$ closed under finite intersection?

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Can anyone help me show that the Cartesian product of the Borel-sigma-algebra is closed under finite intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use that if $A,B,C,D$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then $(A\times B)\cap(C\times D)=(A\cap C)\times(B\cap D)$.